# what does this syntax mean for c

Tags: c, syntax

I know that I am asking an incredibly low level question, but I am unfamiliar with C and am trying to convert an expression to Objective-C. What does this mean?

```
double (*x)[2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Convert to objective-c? C code is completely valid in objc, there is no conversion necessary.

Comment: Yes...my c function is being used in my Objective-C code, but I need to call the function, and due to my obvious lack of C knowledge, I needed to know what parameters to call it with.

Comment: I think that was Richard's point (I know it certainly was mine): you can't say you know Obj-C if you don't know C, due to Obj-C being a strict superset of C... thus, no "conversion" needs to take place, just a bit more foundational knowledge of Obj-C. You would invoke that function exactly the same way in Obj-C as in C.

Comment: You might find http://cdecl.org/ to be helpful in deciphering things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a semicolon at the end, it declares and defines a pointer (named `x`) to a array of 2 doubles. If it's a function (or method) argument, its type is the same: a pointer to an array of 2 doubles.

Answer (score 2):

C is already valid Objective-C, so you should be fine :P

For a nonfacetious answer, it allocates x as a pointer to a two-element array of doubles (so the size of what the pointer is referencing is `2 * sizeof(double)`).